# Where does the program return to when one view calls a 2nd view and the 2nd view closes?

Tags: xcode, global-variables, viewcontroller

I've been working all day on that classic problem of passing variable values between views. (I've read and typed in almost every example I've found in my books and on the net!)
My second view is a picker, and I have to retrieve the row value and send it back to the calling program. I've managed to pass data from the first view to the picker's view, but what method runs in the first view controller when the 2nd view controller closes? That is, where do I put the code to receive the picker's value?

Incidentally, I settled on the Shared Instances method of passing the values, found at http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/05/the-death-of-global-variables/

Thanks,
-Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question in *Sams Teach Yourself iPad in 24 Hours*. The code goes into the viewWillAppear method. It's like ViewDidLoad but it's for returning to the View from a different View. If you are updating a label, for example, on the first view with data set by the second view, the data being passed is set into the label in viewWillAppear.